# jQuery bug - Solution needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a page in WordPress which has a jQuery dropdown, show/hide div based on the selection. then I have custom posts in content.

Here is the bug which I am trying to fix. - [website link](https://staging-buildertrendcom.temp312.kinsta.cloud/podcasts/the-better-way/)

when I select "season 1" from the dropdown, all is good. but if you click one of the posts and go into the post, and then click the back arrow in the browser, "Season 1" will still appear in the dropdown, but Season 2 posts will appear in the content.  I have to then select "season 2" and then "Season 1" to bring up season 1 posts again.

This is the jQuery I am using to show/hide based on dropdown selection.

```
/*-- Season 2 first --- */

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.js-podcast-list').hide()

  /*  
    SET SEASON TO SHOW ON PAGE LOAD
  */
  $('#season-2, #season-1').hide()
  var season = $('#selectMe option:selected').val()
  $('#' + season).show()

  /*  
    SET SEASON TO SHOW ON #selectMe CHANGE
  */
  $('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.js-podcast-list').hide()
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show()
  })
})
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to how I can fix this or another jQuery/javascript method that would work?. Thank you for your time!.

Comment: Can you share you html as well?

Comment: Have you considered modifying the url and parsing it on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser are autocompleting the select with your previous selected value.
To prevent this, add the autocomplete attribute like this :

```
<select autocomplete="off">[...]</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor a bit and extract the select

```
  /*  
    SET SEASON TO SHOW ON #selectMe CHANGE
  */
  $('#selectMe').change(updateSeason);

  function updateSeason(){
    $('.js-podcast-list').hide()
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show()
  }
```

Then also just call the method on page show.

```
$(window).on('pageshow', updateSeason);
```

this may not be 100% but it'll get you started.

Side note, your doc ready only needs this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.js-podcast-list').hide()

  $('#season-2, #season-1').hide()
  
  /*  
    SET SEASON TO SHOW ON PAGE LOAD
  */
  updateSeason();
})
```

Edit:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // On page load, hide everything
    $('.js-podcast-list').hide() 
    $('#season-2, #season-1').hide()
    
    // Update what is visible
    updateSeason();

});

function updateSeason() {
    jQuery('.js-podcast-list').hide() // did you want this as show?
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(#selectMe).val()).show()
}
  
jQuery('#selectMe').change(updateSeason);
  
jQuery(window).on('pageshow', updateSeason);
```

Comment: Hi @Blue, I was not able to get this working. Not sure what i did wring with this?           
``` lang-js
   /*-- Season 2 first --- */

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.js-podcast-list').hide()

    $('#season-2, #season-1').hide()
    
    /*  
      SET SEASON TO SHOW ON PAGE LOAD
    */
    updateSeason();

      /*  
    SET SEASON TO SHOW ON #selectMe CHANGE
  */
  $('#selectMe').change(updateSeason);

  function updateSeason(){
    $('.js-podcast-list').hide()
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show()
  }

  $(window).on('pageshow', updateSeason);

});```

Comment: Hi @BlueEyedBehemoth.  I followed your updated solution, but not the dropdown does not work,  shows both season  1 and season 2 episodes.  https://staging-buildertrendcom.temp312.kinsta.cloud/podcasts/the-better-way/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLSelectElement.updateSeason (the-better-way.js?ver=5.7.2:41)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at HTMLSelectElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)

Change $ to jQuery

Comment: @Jon I see your bug is fixed and you're using my answer as your code. I also see duplicate code you should get rid of.  `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.js-podcast-list').hide()

  /*  
    SET SEASON TO SHOW ON PAGE LOAD
  */
  $('#season-2, #season-1').hide()
  var season = $('#selectMe option:selected').val()
  $('#' + season).show()

  /*  
    SET SEASON TO SHOW ON #selectMe CHANGE
  */
  $('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.js-podcast-list').hide()
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show()
  })
})`